# Using an Association as a Manipulate variable?

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, associations

I would like to use an association in a Manipulate or a DynamicModule.

Specifically, I'd like to click to change the Values of a list of Keys of an Association.

Here is some non-working code that (hopefully) illustrates the functionality I am looking for:

```
 DynamicModule[{assoc = <|"category 1" -> True, "category 2" -> True, 
    "category 3" -> False |>},
 {TogglerBar[Dynamic[assoc],
   {(assoc["category 1"] = Not[assoc["category 1"]]) -> "1",
    (assoc["category 2"] = Not[assoc["category 2"]]) -> "2",
    (assoc["category 3"] = Not[assoc["category 3"]]) -> "3"
    }
   
   ], Dynamic[assoc]}
 ]
```

The intention was to change the values of the association, and not the whole association.

I suspect this is related to an Association's immutability. The same behavior also occurs for List:

```
DynamicModule[
 {list = {True, False, True}},
 {TogglerBar[Dynamic[list],
   {(list[[1]] = Not[list[[1]]]) -> "1",
    (list[[2]] = Not[list[[2]]]) -> "2",
    (list[[3]] = Not[list[[3]]]) -> "3"
    }
   
   ], Dynamic[list]}
 ]
```

Can anyone see a way dynamically manipulate parts of an association?

Comment: You should be able to do whatever you want with the second argument of `Dynamic`. I leave this comment as a hint for others who might have time to experiment.

Comment: Good hint. This almost works: `DynamicModule[{assoc = <|"category 1" -> True, "category 2" -> True, 
    "category 3" -> False|>, 
  which = "category 1"}, {RadioButtonBar[
   Dynamic[which, (assoc[#] = ! assoc[#]) &],
   {"category 1" -> "1",
    "category 2" -> "2",
    "category 2" -> "3"
    }], Dynamic[{which, assoc}]}]`

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure this is what you want, but hopefully close enough to get you started. I think you want an association that gets modified based on the value of the TogglerBar where the TogglerBar is basically the indexes into the values of the association. So, let's separate the association itself from the TogglerBar stuff. Here's the association:

```
MyKeys={"category 1","category 2","category 3"};
MyDefaultValues={True,True,False};
MyAssociation=AssociationThread[MyKeys,MyDefaultValues]
(*<|category 1->True,category 2->True,category 3->False|>*)
```

Here's a variable to hold the update instructions along with a TogglerBar:

```
valsToUpdate={};
TogglerBar[Dynamic[valsToUpdate],Range[3]]
```

And here is a Dynamic to handle the update:

```
Dynamic[
  MyAssociation=
    AssociationThread[
      MyKeys,
      MapAt[Not,MyDefaultValues,List/@valsToUpdate]]]
```

Comment: Thanks @leicr, this has the right behavior.  I'm still wondering if there might be a solution that changes a value of the association "in place" rather than overwriting the association each time.

Comment: I suppose you could create your own control that used buttons whose actions did the updating. ToggleBar, as far as I know, doesn't "fire" actions. It just dynamically updates its variable.